# Como mapear un array de objetos en json en un array de objetos

Tags: java, api, get

En una API a la hora de hacer una llama GET soy capaz de la respuesta convertirla en su representación en objeto java.

```
{
  "Id": "3-4779-841c-08f88e1d3889",
  "Data": "{'name':'nombre','city':'ciudad'}"
}

final HttpResponseBean httpResponseBean = this.httpIntegrator.getRequest(
                MessageFormat.format(
                    Dao.URL_PATTERN
                    , this.Scheme
                    , this.Url
                    , this.Port
                    , Dao.CONTEXT_PATH));

        final byte[] payload = httpResponseBean.getPayload();
        return mapper.readValue(payload, Bean.class);
```

Esto funciona perfectamente pero ahora tengo que manejar la respuesta que obtengo de un GET. Pero en esta ocasión en vez de manejar de responderme un único valor obtengo la lista entera de valores. Si soy capaz de mapear un objeto como podría mapear una respuesta la cual tengo una array de esos objetos en formato JSON

```
[
        {
            "Id": "3-4779-841c-08f88e1d3889",
            "Data": "{'name':'nombre','city':'ciudad'}"
        }, 
        {
            "Id": "3-4779-841c-98f28e1d3689",
            "Data": "{'name':'nombre','city':'ciudad'}"
        },
        {
            "Id": "3-0729-891c-08f48s1d3889",
            "Data": "{'name':'nombre','city':'ciudad'}"
        }, 
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno el flujo es como el de arriba se hace la petición GET y con la respuesta se hace lo siguiente:

```
    final byte[] payload = httpResponseBean.getPayload();
    final String decodedPayload = new String(payload, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final List<Bean> beans= Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(decodedPayload, Bean[].class));

    final List<String> beanIds = new ArrayList<>();
    beans.forEach(bean -> {
        beanIds.add(beans.getBeanId());
    });

    return beanIds;
```